# What are the alternatives to using allow.sysvipc in a jail running PostgreSQL in FreeBSD

Tags: security, freebsd, postgresql, bsd

This question is prompted by [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/159207/what-are-the-security-implications-of-using-allow-sysvipc-in-a-freebsd-jail) one.

I've set up a jail to run PostgreSQL but without `allow.sysvipc` when creating the jail (or setting the relevant rc.conf entries), the system call to `shmget` are blocked and PostgreSQL won't run.  The problem is that by setting `allow.sysvipc` the whole point of having a jail is eliminated.

Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full virtualization instead of jails (like KVM). (Or have someone fix jails in FreeBSD so they actually separate things).

PostgreSQL will always require shared memory and there is no way around it.

Comment: They do separate things.  But sometimes, they separate the functionality from the jail when what's wanted is split views of the functionality.  ;)